# sIFR text stretched/blurry in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sifr

**Answered**

The best answer below was good for the bounty, but user Aaron's answer is the correct answer. Setting:

```
.sIFR-flash {
width:100%;
}
```

corrects the issue in Chrome. Sadly, I cannot change my best answer as I guess that's how bounties work.

**Answered**

---

I seem to be having some issues with Chrome specifically rendering sIFR replaced text stretched out (and blurry) in it's flash container. No other browser does this (looks good in IE6,7,8, FF, Safari, Opera). Is this a known bug/does anyone have a workaround?

Here's an example you can look at on this site: http://uvph.com/

And here's the replace code:

```
// -- configure sifr
var futura = { src: '/swf/bfuturah.swf' };

sIFR.activate(futura);

sIFR.replace(futura, {
    css: [
        '.sIFR-root { background-color:transparent; color: #999999; font-size:24px; text-transform:uppercase; }'
    ],
    fitExactly      : true,
    forceClear      : true,
    forceSingleLine : true,
    selector        : 'h2',
    transparent     : true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm this is a really strange one. i've uploaded a testcase of your site to my server and everything works fine in chrome. the much better alternative to sifr is http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ its much smaller and much faster, but you cant select the text anymore

Comment: Weird. Well, you fixed it so you get the bounty for now :) The background image isn't loading in your test so maybe it's that.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that setting the width of .sIFR-flash to 100% seems to correct the issue.

Comment: Nice, can't wait to try this.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. This is, indeed the correct answer. I guess I cannot change my "best answer" since it was a bounty. Thanks, Aaron.

Answer (score 3):

I can't use @font-face as my font embeds poorly and I need selectable text. To fix the vertical stretching for my sIFR in IE9 I added
display:block;
height:1.45em;
to the .sIFR-flash
which seemed to match up to IE8 and Firefox 
I also used a body font-size of 70%
It gives an extra little flicker while loading but the stretching has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Use @font-face property of CSS. It is now supported across all popular browsers(including IE and Chrome). http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2009/09/20/font-face-in-depth/ has a very good post about using @font-face across all browsers and the page itself uses custom fonts. Worth checking =)

Comment: Agreed. Don't serve sIFR to browsers that can support @font-face. If you're going to use sIFR or friends, have your server only serve them to browsers that need it (older IE, mostly).

Comment: Apparently they insist on non-CSS solutions. I'm sure they have a good reason but still, if you have time to read that article, it'll make your life much better for custom fonts =)

Comment: It is what it is gentlemen. I typically use Cufon but this site was made before Chrome was in release.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: set "forceSingleLine" to "false".
If this still doesn't help: check the CSS properties of the text you want to be rendered. Display-type of the rendered element itself (not the parent!) should be "block", otherwise "width: 100%" has no effect at all. The best results for Chrome can be achieved if sIFR is applied to a block element with fixed width - but this approach will not always be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's something odd between Chrome and the Flash player. It's as if the Flash movie is scaled up incorrectly. The movie fixes itself when you click on it.

What if you set `sIFR.useDomLoaded = false` before `sIFR.activate()`?

Comment: No dice, useDomLoaded has no effect.

Comment: Any chance you can reproduce this in a standalone page? No other HTML, CSS, replacements etc?

Comment: Yeah, I'll give it a shot this weekend.

Comment: Removed all css and js except sifr and it still seems to happen.

Comment: Do you have a copy of that online somewhere?